# Rolling resistance and net force on a vehicle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

I'm working on a simple car game and trying to figure out the physics. If the net force on the car is:

> Fn = Ft + Fd + Frr + Fg

where:

- Fn = total force
- Ft = tractive force
- Fd = aerodynamic drag
- Frr = rolling resistance
- Fg = gravitational force

and we use the following to calculate rolling resistance:

> Frr = -Coef * Mass * Gravity * Cos(Angle)

For a car with rubber tyres that means when it is sitting in neutral on level ground it has a net force of about -105 Newtons (due to rolling resistance) which means the car starts rolling backwards. Obviously this is not correct so does that mean that the above formula for net force is also incorrect? Can someone explain how rolling resistance should be calculated in my  game? Sorry if my formatting is not right, I don't come here often, also my knowledge of physics is very limited.

Comment: A net force means that the car is accelerating, per Newton's 2nd law.  Also, I have done coast down tests in the past to infer rolling resistance vs. wind drag.  For an aerodynamic car traveling at 60 mph, the vehicle experiences approximately 50% wind drag and 50% rolling resistance.  Note that wind drag increases as the square of the velocity, so that information should give you a constraint to test your model against.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula for $F_{rr}$ is correct except that the sign can be plus or minus, as for static friction.

Like static and kinetic friction, the force of rolling resistance opposes motion. So if the vehicle does not move then the rolling resistance is zero. If the engine tries to push the vehicle forwards then $F_{rr}$ would be backwards, and *vice versa*. If the vehicle rolls backwards then $F_{rr}$ would be in the forward direction.

The effect of rolling resistance on a stationary vehicle is the same as for static friction : the vehicle does not start moving until you apply a force of $F_{rr}$ or greater. Once the vehicle is moving rolling resistance is like kinetic friction : it applies a constant retarding force.

Your formula for $F_n$ is missing the normal reaction force $N$ acting upwards on the vehicle from the road. You should be aware that forces are **vectors** - their directions are important as well as their magnitudes. $F_g$ acts vertically, $N$ is perpendicular to the road whereas $F_{rr}, F_d$ and $F_t$ are parallel to the road. So this formula is a vector equation : directions must be taken account of.

Answer (score 0):

No sliding of the wheels occurs for a rolling object, so rolling resistance is always static friction.  The rolling resistance does not actually remove kinetic energy from the car.  It converts translational kinetic energy ($\frac{1}{2}mv^2$) to rotational kinetic energy within the wheels and tires ($\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$).  It will be only as large as needed so as to keep the wheel turning synchronized with the velocity of the car.  This is just big enough to keep the wheels from sliding.  If the needed force is larger than the allowed static friction, the wheels slide and the friction becomes kinetic.  If the vehicle doesn't speed up or slow down, then the rolling energy of the wheels doesn't change.  Rolling resistance would be zero.  It opposes velocity when the car speeds up, using translational velocity to speed up the wheel angular velocity.  Rolling resistance points in the direction of velocity when slowing the car, converting rotational kinetic energy back to translational kinetic energy.